# How to do Postgresql injection in to_tsquery?

Tags: database, postgresql, security, sql-injection

so the requirement is simple, my query is:

```
 select to_tsquery('XXX');
```

What should be my string `'XXX'` so that:
`to_tsquery('XXX')` returns `pg_sleep(2)`

Is there any way to do it?

PS: I am trying it for good motive.

Comment: No `tsvector` can look like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way for to_tsquery('XXX') to return `pg_sleep(2)`. But if you just want to do something similar to `select pg_sleep(2);` you can do this:

```
select to_tsquery('XXX'||pg_sleep(2)); -- Simple sleep
select to_tsquery('XXX'||(select case when (<your_condition_here>) then pg_sleep(10) else pg_sleep(0) end)); -- Conditional sleep
```